# NServiceBus Queue Naming Conventions

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, naming

Has anyone developed a decent naming convention for MSMQ queues when using NServiceBus, where there are many queues on a single server, but also on other servers?

The system I'm developing will have many discrete subscbribers across a set of servers, and some of the servers will run multiple unrelated applications.

It would be nice to be able to open the msmq management console and immediately know the purpose for all the queues.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you'll find as many different ways to do this as you'll find developers.

We don't really have any non-NServiceBus queues, so we have no need to prefix them "nsb_" like Adam Fyles suggested.

We like to do a dot-separated notation that roughly mimics class namespaces, like "ProjectName.QueueName".

Or for really big projects, where there's more Udi-style service boundary analysis going on, we'll do something more like "BigProjectName.ServiceName.QueueName".

We have an NServiceBus cluster that runs our distributors, and this is where we locate our error queue, so every endpoint uses something like "Error@NSBCluster". This enables us to monitor the system from one place.

Comment: +1 for the central error ( and audit) queue, don't have to be on a cluster though

Comment: Thanks David, that's a combination of what hugh and I were thinking. "Use the most appropriate naming for the situation".

Answer (score 1):

What I do

- ApplicationName.Input
- ApplicationName.Error
- ApplicationName.Input.Audit

Comment: Do you ever need another layer in that method, like <ApplicationName>.<Component>.<QueueType>?

Comment: Nope. The reason for this is my service composition or granularity. I only have one endpoint per NSB generic host.

Answer (score 1):

We use nsb_$endpoint_$function where $function = error or audit.  $function is left off for just the endpoint.  We also make this match the Display Name and Service Name when installing the host.  Our admins like being able to match the process to the service and then to the queue.